# UIActivityIndicatorView in cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, uikit, uiactivityindicatorview

**Hi guys!** 
Currently discovering cocos2d framework. 
Now I'm trying to use **UIKit** stuff in **cocos2d** project.

**What I'm doing:** I've added the methods:

```
    -(void)activityIndicatorRun {
        spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
        spinner.color = [UIColor orangeColor];
        spinner.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
        [spinner startAnimating];
        [self scheduleOnce:@selector(activityIndicatorStop) delay:5.0f];
    }
```

**AND**

```
-(void)activityIndicatorStop {
   [spinner stopAnimating];
}
```

After I added this like of code to my **init** method:

```
[self scheduleOnce:@selector(activityIndicatorRun) delay:54];
```

I think that I need to add a subview to my view. But I'm not sure about how you can do this, and where.

**Question:** Can anyone help me?

*Thanks in advance!*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add UIKit components as subview of your underlying OpenGL ES view in your cocos2d app.

For cocos2d-iphone 0.99/1.0:

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:spinner];
```

For 2.x:

```
// CCDirector is subclass of UIViewController in 2.x on iOS
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview:spinner];
```

Comment: Thanks! I've added this line of code exactly before the call of activityIndicator(the call is described in the message). But the spinner didn't appear after 54 second.

Comment: I haven't used `UIActivityIndicatorView` in my cocos2d apps before :| Let me have a try...

Comment: Sure! I'm a biginner with cocos2d. It's really easy. But I stuck over here with UIKit. I didn't have any problems to add UIAlertView, obviously because you don't need to add any subviews there.

Comment: I had a try with adding the `addSubview` statement right before `[spinner startAnimating];`, and the indicator appeared in the left-top corner on my app...